# Windows Service wrapping a Java Process not stopping from time to time

Tags: java, windows, service, install4j

I a building a custom Java Application that is wrapped into a Windows Service by Install4J , most of the time everything works just fine , but from time to time the service cannot be stopped , it just hangs there until widows displays the timeout error message. The user must go and kill the process manually and then everything is fine.

By checking the app logs I can tell that nothing is happening , the app is not getting any signal from windows.

I have also registered a shutdown hook via Runtime but in the case when the service is not stopping this hook is called at all. It's like the kill signal doesn't get trough to the Java VM

Has anyone encountered an issue like this ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Mircea

Comment: You could use the jstack tool in the JDK to get a thread dump of your process

Comment: Tried that , also used jprofiler to take a peek at the wrapped process , but nothing seems out of the ordinary , the process is running fine.  It just won't stop ...

Comment: Have you tried running the service executable with the /status and the /stop arguments from an elevated command prompt? What does it print in either case?

Comment: Yes, no output. The service goes into stopped mode and nothing happens. Thanks.

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com for access to the current build. There may be a related issue that we have fixed recently.

Comment: The issue was fixed by the Install4j - Support and released in install4j 5.1.12 , thank you.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I just added this as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in install4j 5.1.12.